# App publishing in different country and different language

Tags: android, app-store

I have created an app and app language is English but I wanted to publish the app in different countries and descriptive content and images for publishing should be shown as per native languages according to country.

Is there any procedure to upload the app and publish as per their native languages (Only description and images which are using to publish the app).

Please guide me

Comment: Please, refer to the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Comment: I can't see any option to select the country while uploading the App

Answer (score 1):

Use [This guide from Google](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en).

1. Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console.
2. Select an app.
3. On the left menu, click Store Listing.
4. Under "Product Details," click Manage translations.
5. Select Add your own translation text.
6. Choose a language.
   Add your translations.
7. Near the top of the page, click Publish app (new apps) or Submit update(existing apps).

**Edit**

For the app store follow [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/DisplayInMoreLanguages.html) guide.

Comment: Thank John.. That means we can publish the app in multiple countries as per their native languages... Can you please guide me for App store as well please?

Comment: @byoxuser I've edited my answer, please check the edit

Comment: Thanks ...John...Can u please explain for iOS Apps as well